# How can I prevent binding random texture in OpenGL Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I store my textures IDs in `GLuint textures[]` array. When I try to bind first of them (textres[0]) i get random one instead. Sometimes good, but mostly not. Every other works just fine. I also tried binding this texture in other drawing methods and it behaved the same way. My loading function:

```
int Screen::loadTextures()
{
    Images.clear();

    Images.append(QImage("APPLE.png"));
    Images.append(QImage("V.png"));
    Images.append(QImage("TAIL.png"));
    Images.append(QImage("DTOR.png"));
    Images.append(QImage("HEAD.png"));
    Images.append(QImage("BACK.png"));
    Images.append((QImage("PLUS10.png")));
    Images.append((QImage("SPEEDUP.png")));

    for(int i = 0; i<Images.size(); ++i)
    {
        Images[i] = QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(Images[i]);
        if(Images[i].isNull()) return 0;
    }

    textures = new GLuint[Images.size()];
    glGenTextures(Images.size(), &textures[Images.size()]);

    for(int i=0; i<Images.size(); ++i)
    {
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,textures[i]);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, Images[i].width(), Images[i].height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, Images[i].bits());
    }

    return 1;
}
```

and painting:

```
void Screen::drawApple(int X, int Y)
{
    #define JEDNOSTKA = 0.2
    glPushMatrix();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,textures[0]);

    glTranslated(X*JEDNOSTKA, Y*JEDNOSTKA,0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

    glTexCoord2f(0,1);
    glVertex3d(-JEDNOSTKA/2, JEDNOSTKA/2,0);
    glTexCoord2f(1,1);
    glVertex3d( JEDNOSTKA/2, JEDNOSTKA/2,0);
    glTexCoord2f(1,0);
    glVertex3d( JEDNOSTKA/2,-JEDNOSTKA/2,0);
    glTexCoord2f(0,0);
    glVertex3d(-JEDNOSTKA/2,-JEDNOSTKA/2,0);

    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();

}
```

Comment: Passing `&textures[Images.size()]` to `glGenTextures` incorrect. The texture-name array will not be correctly initialized.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
&textures[Images.size()]
```

which in fact is passing the addres of a first uint OUTSIDE of the array you should use

```
glGenTextures(Images.size(), textures);
```

since textures is uint pointer that points to the first element of the array.